# Quais os critérios de aprovação que estamos a usar na fila edição?

Tags: debate, edição, respostas, edições-sugeridas, filas-de-análise

Mais uma vez uma edição que deixa muito a desejar, tirando a parte de «um» para «uma» gostava de saber quais os critérios de aprovação que estamos a usar ultimamente?

A primeira parte é uma mudança de pt-PT para pt-BR, já a segunda apaga uma frase que altera o sentido da minha resposta... Muito estranha esta aprovação. De referir que houve também um rejeição.

Cada vez me dá menos vontade de moderar/responder no site.

Resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115907/7210

Aprovação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/94154

Comment: Eu vi essa edição, pensei em fazer o revert, mas assim como você, minha paciencia acabou. Quem frequenta o chat vai se lembrar da inumeras edições que reportei, mas fica só nisso mesmo. To cansado de relatar esse tipo de edição, mas não adianta, é perda de tempo. Se você chama a atenção dos editores, quando não recebe uma resposta rude, fica com fama de chato.

Comment: Bem vindo ao clube! **Nota:** Traga cerveja.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olhando para essa edição sugerida e para o comentário do autor, ela me pareceu ser bem plausível de aprovação. Dos três revisores, dois aprovaram sem problemas e um só rejeitou porque achou que as mudanças foram pequenas demais. **Se eu fosse revisar isso, eu aprovaria.**

Vejamos as mudanças:

> "*depois de um transferência.*" --> "*depois de um**a** transferência.*"

Isso era um erro de concordância nominal mesmo.

> "*pegar **nos** bytes todos de um arquivo e somá-los*" --> "*pegar **os** bytes todos de um arquivo e somá-los*"

Na minha opinião, a segunda forma soa mais natural e a primeira é estranha. A primeira forma me remete a alguém pegando os bytes na mão fisicamente ou algo do tipo, enquanto que a segunda me remete que *"juntar"*  ou *"agrupar"* seria um sinônimo de "*pegar*". Nunca imaginaria que isso é algum tipo de diferença entre pt-PT e pt-BR.

> "*Esse valor tem de ser o mesmo após uma transferência.*" --> [removido]

Isso daqui me chamou mais a atenção, mas ao ver o texto "*Informação repetindo*" do autor da edição, facilmente eu seria convencido de que ele sabe o que está fazendo. Lendo com calma, provavelmente ele interpretou errado e pensou que você apenas estava sendo redundante. Eu também interpretei errado após ler duas vezes, e só insisti até entender na terceira tentativa porque se estivesse certo, você não estaria aqui no meta reclamando. Sugiro que reescreva assim para que ninguém mais tenha dúvidas:

> Depois de uma transferência, esse valor do *checksum* deve ser o mesmo tanto no arquivo enviado pelo remetente quanto no recebido pelo destinatário.

Por fim, quando quiser reclamar de edições sugeridas e aprovadas, basta postar um comentário com um "*@AutorDaEdição*" e ele será notificado. Quem edita a pergunta ou resposta também é passível de ser notificado por comentários através do uso do "*@*". Já fiz isso algumas vezes, principalmente quando acabo tendo que reverter a edição de alguém, seja total ou parcialmente.

Comment: Acho que não me expliquei bem, o que não é concordância de idioma é o caso dos bytes e não o "uma".

Comment: Victor o problema aqui não é o editor, e sim a aprovação. Como eu disse o erro de concordância de uma e um foi uma edição certa. Tudo o resto não.

Comment: Victor eu acho grave uma edição ser aprovada quando se muda o texto da resposta, apagando trechos, sem a aprovação do autor. Mudou o sentido da resposta, mas mesmo que não mudasse. É uma das regras do site.

Comment: @JorgeB. Bem, para isso, você pode postar um comentário para conversar com quem fez isso, tal como sugeri. Eu **acho** que ele não percebeu que estava mudando o sentido da resposta, dado que colocou o comentário de "*Informação repetindo*". Como você bem sabe, um dos pilaress da qualidade do site funciona com base em edições feitas por pessoas, mas pessoas erram, todos erram, e eu também já errei bastante. E sinceramente, já vi coisas bem piores serem aprovadas em edições e a solução é simples, é editar de novo.

Comment: Victor acho que o problema não foi só do editor. Eu nunca aprovaria uma edição dessas sem ter a certeza da intenção do autor. Iria no mínimo comentar.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas daí você entra em um outro ponto, é muito comum as pessoas terem certezas de coisas que no fundo são falsas. Não posso falar pelo usuário em questão, mas falando por mim, edito postagens de outros usuários com muita frequência, especialmente porque várias das postagens do site têm um péssimo português e uma péssima formatação. Frequentemente posto comentários quando encontro coisas duvidosas ou que não entendo, mas também posso errar pensando que entendi uma coisa com certeza quando isso não é verdade.

Comment: E verdade sim senhor, tens razão. De qualquer forma fica o alerta. A mim, pareceu-me evidente a má edição, mas posso estar a ser exagerado...